# I'm using socket.io but there's no communication between client and server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm developing a multiplayer chess game using node js with socket.io. The game displays fine in the index.html file and works fine on the server when I run it on localhost:8080. However, the chess moves aren't being submitted to the other player, even though I did everything right. What's missing? I have socket.io installed correctly

I've tried re-watching the tutorial on youtube over and over again to spot my mistake, but I can't. I did everything accordingly. I must be missing something. here's the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Isfqigjo7fQ&t=1621s

EDIT

here is the link to the tutorial on building the multiplayer chess game http://dwcares.com/2015/10/21/realchess/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chess</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chessboard-0.3.0.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="chessboard-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chess.js/0.10.2/chess.js"></script>
      <script src ="lib/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="board" style="width: 400px"></div>


      <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
        var board = ChessBoard('board', 'start');


var board,
  game = new Chess();

var removeGreySquares = function() {
  $('#board .square-55d63').css('background', '');
};

var greySquare = function(square) {
  var squareEl = $('#board .square-' + square);

  var background = '#a9a9a9';
  if (squareEl.hasClass('black-3c85d') === true) {
    background = '#696969';
  }

  squareEl.css('background', background);
};

var onDragStart = function(source, piece) {
  // do not pick up pieces if the game is over
  // or if it's not that side's turn
  if (game.game_over() === true ||
      (game.turn() === 'w' && piece.search(/^b/) !== -1) ||
      (game.turn() === 'b' && piece.search(/^w/) !== -1)) {
    return false;
  }
};

var onDrop = function(source, target) {
  removeGreySquares();

  // see if the move is legal
  var move = game.move({
    from: source,
    to: target,
    promotion: 'q' // NOTE: always promote to a queen for example simplicity
  });

  // illegal move
  if (move === null) return 'snapback';
};

var onMouseoverSquare = function(square, piece) {
  // get list of possible moves for this square
  var moves = game.moves({
    square: square,
    verbose: true
  });

  // exit if there are no moves available for this square
  if (moves.length === 0) return;

  // highlight the square they moused over
  greySquare(square);

  // highlight the possible squares for this piece
  for (var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
    greySquare(moves[i].to);
  }
};

var onMouseoutSquare = function(square, piece) {
  removeGreySquares();
};

var onSnapEnd = function() {
  board.position(game.fen());
};

var cfg = {
  draggable: true,
  position: 'start',
  onDragStart: onDragStart,
  onDrop: onDrop,
  onMouseoutSquare: onMouseoutSquare,
  onMouseoverSquare: onMouseoverSquare,
  onSnapEnd: onSnapEnd
};
board = ChessBoard('board', cfg);

var socket = io();
msgButton.onclick = function(e) {
    socket.emit("message", "hello boi");
}



var handleMove = function(source, target) {
    var move = game.move({from: source, to: target});

    if (move === null) return "snapback";
    else socket.emit("move", move);
};



socket.on("move", function(msg) {
    game.move(msg);
    board.position(game.fen());
});













    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

below is my server file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static("[ublic]"));
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var path = require('path');
var public = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
var io = require("socket.io")(http);


// viewed at http://localhost:8080
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(public, 'index.html'));
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user has connected');

    socket.on("message", function(msg) {
        console.log("Message from client: "+ msg);
    });


    socket.on("move", function(msg) {
        socket.broadcast.emit("move", msg);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('a user disconnected');
  });

});




http.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8080');
});

app.use('/', express.static(public));
```

What I need is for the chess game to work properly where the moves are submitted correctly between 2 players

Comment: Your IO server is running on port `8080` (as in your code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your code and found some few things which need some adjustment.

1. Your io connection as mentioned above -- add the port as

```js
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

2. Then there is a bug, you are using undeclared variable msgButton, add the button in html then define it

```js
var msgButton = $('button');
```

3. You are reclaring socket, which has already declared and connected. So remove this

```js
 var socket = io();
```

4. msgButton being a jQuery object, it has no method onclick. Change the following

```js
 msgButton.onclick = function (e) {
            socket.emit("message", "hello boi");
        }
```

to

```js
msgButton.click(function (e) {
            socket.emit("message", "hello boi");
        });
```

5. The handlemove function is not being called, hence no move can be emited. I tracked the move emit to onDrop function. So moving the logic for emiting move event to this function did the trick. So change onDrop to

```js
var onDrop = function (source, target) {
            removeGreySquares();

            // see if the move is legal
            var move = game.move({
                from: source,
                to: target,
                promotion: 'q' // NOTE: always promote to a queen for example simplicity
            });
            // console.log('=== dron');

            // illegal move
            if (move === null) {
                return 'snapback';
            } else {
                socket.emit("move", move)
            }
            
        };
```

6. Final code in script tag

```js
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8088');
        var board = ChessBoard('board', 'start');

        var msgButton = $('button');

        // $('.msgButton').click(() => {
        //   console.log('Hello');
        // });


        var board,
            game = new Chess();

        var removeGreySquares = function () {
            $('#board .square-55d63').css('background', '');
        };

        var greySquare = function (square) {
            var squareEl = $('#board .square-' + square);

            var background = '#a9a9a9';
            if (squareEl.hasClass('black-3c85d') === true) {
                background = '#696969';
            }

            squareEl.css('background', background);
        };

        var onDragStart = function (source, piece) {
            // do not pick up pieces if the game is over
            // or if it's not that side's turn
            if (game.game_over() === true ||
                (game.turn() === 'w' && piece.search(/^b/) !== -1) ||
                (game.turn() === 'b' && piece.search(/^w/) !== -1)) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        var onDrop = function (source, target) {
            removeGreySquares();

            // see if the move is legal
            var move = game.move({
                from: source,
                to: target,
                promotion: 'q' // NOTE: always promote to a queen for example simplicity
            });
            // console.log('=== dron');

            // illegal move
            if (move === null) {
                console.log('invalid');
                return 'snapback';
            } else {
                console.log('valid');
                socket.emit("move", move)
            }
            
        };

        var onMouseoverSquare = function (square, piece) {
            // get list of possible moves for this square
            var moves = game.moves({
                square: square,
                verbose: true
            });

            // exit if there are no moves available for this square
            if (moves.length === 0) return;

            // highlight the square they moused over
            greySquare(square);

            // highlight the possible squares for this piece
            for (var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
                greySquare(moves[i].to);
            }
        };

        var onMouseoutSquare = function (square, piece) {
            removeGreySquares();
        };

        var onSnapEnd = function () {
            board.position(game.fen());
        };

        var cfg = {
            draggable: true,
            position: 'start',
            onDragStart: onDragStart,
            onDrop: onDrop,
            onMouseoutSquare: onMouseoutSquare,
            onMouseoverSquare: onMouseoverSquare,
            onSnapEnd: onSnapEnd
        };
        board = ChessBoard('board', cfg);

        // var socket = io();
        msgButton.click(function (e) {
            console.log('++clicked');
            socket.emit("message", "hello boi");
        });

        var handleMove = function (source, target) {
            var move = game.move({ from: source, to: target });
            console.log('===');

            if (move === null) return "snapback";
            else socket.emit("move", move);
        };

        socket.on("move", function (msg) {
            console.log('++move received: ', msg);
            game.move(msg);
            board.position(game.fen());
        });
```

7. Not related though,  but use of console.log or any other logging mechanisms is very helpful when trying to find bugs in js. I left some!

Answer (score 2):

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

Your server is running on 8080 however you are trying to connect :80. This should fix the problem.

Comment: I don't understand, where do I put this line of code. the client or server? I've put it in the server and I got an error because "io.connect is not a function"

Comment: @MrHunchoJack Add this to your client

Comment: I've done this and replaced that line of code. However I still have no communication between client and server. The chess moves aren't submitting. However I am still getting a "user has connected" and "user has disconnected" message whenever a tab opens or closes. what's going on

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that `handleMove` is never called? I can't see it in the code you provided.

**Edit**: Also you are connecting using `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');`

The http port is `80` by default. Try connecting to `http://localhost:8080`

To do that, change your script in the HTML file:

```
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
    var board = ChessBoard('board', 'start');
    (...)
```

to

```
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    var board = ChessBoard('board', 'start');
    (...)
```

When you have done that, you need to actually emit the `move` message.
Add this line in your `onDrop` function:

```
else socket.emit("move", move);
```

It should now look like this:

```
var onDrop = function(source, target) {
  removeGreySquares();

  // see if the move is legal
  var move = game.move({
    from: source,
    to: target,
    promotion: 'q' // NOTE: always promote to a queen for example simplicity
  });

  // illegal move
  if (move === null) return 'snapback';
  else socket.emit("move", move);
};
```

Comment: The game code is in the html file. handleMove is called in the html file. Am I supposed to call it in the server file too?

Comment: You are declaring a function variable called handleMove in the html file.
See Helens answer, which will probably fix your problem with the connection.

Comment: I updated my answer, this is right after the opening <body> tag. You should find it ;)

Comment: I've done as you asked, but there's still no communication between the server and client. The chess moves aren't being submitted

Comment: Your `onDrop` function calls `move` on the chessgame, and checks if the move is null. After that nothing happens.

Your `handleMove` function calls `socket.emit("move", move);` which should send the move to the other player. But who is calling `handleMove`?

Comment: I'm confused. sorry i'm a beginner with coding

Comment: I've updated my reply again. Please select this as the accepted answer to your question if this solves your problem, and it will, I have tested it.

Also your are using a very old socket.io version. Check this out: https://socket.io/blog/socket-io-2-0-1-2-0-2-and-2-0-3/

Comment: I once again did as you said and I'm still not getting that connection. I'm so frustrated. Do you mind if I send you my source code and you try it? Is it ok if i have your source code and I try yours because i'm getting paranoid and crazy here

Comment: My email is mr.iraqi@live.com if you could please send me the folder. I'll reply with mine

Comment: I sent you a mail :)

Comment: Did you get the email?

Comment: Hello MrHunchoJack! Did my answer solve your problem? Cheers